# How Can I Display All Available Game Center Leaderboards, Rather Than Automatically Showing The Default Leaderboard?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, leaderboard

To load the Game Center leaderboard, I currently call:

```
-(void) showLeaderboard:(NSString*)leaderboardId
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController *viewController = [GKLeaderboardViewController new];
    viewController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    if (leaderboardId)
    {
        viewController.category = leaderboardId;
    }

    [[self topViewController] presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However this always loads up the default leaderboard, and then the user much press the back button to view all the available leaderboards.

Since my method is called from the main menu of my game, this isn't really appropriate to take my player to level 1's leaderboard.

How can I load up the view controller to already just be displaying all the available leaderboards, rather than make my player hit the back button...

Desired Result...
[image: Desired Result...]

What happens...
[image]

Comment: You are correct in setting the `GKLeaderboardViewController` `category` property. Are you sure `leaderboardId` has a value?

Comment: Yes, if i wanted to load a specific leaderboard i would pass it the leaderboardID... However, I jus want to load the overview screen showing all the levels... So i'm trying to pass it @""
And so it just ends up loading the default leaderboard, which in my iTunes connect is Level1's leaderboard...
So, what should I pass it to see the overview of all the leaderboards as seen in the first picture. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `GKLeaderboardViewController`, you are looking for [`GKGameCenterViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

```
GKGameCenterViewController *viewController = [GKGameCenterViewController new];
viewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
```

You may want to load either `GKGameCenterViewController` or `GKLeaderboardViewController` depending on weather `leaderboardId` is set or not.

If that doesn't work, you should try [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276047/2446155).

Comment: This code works perfect for me, since i can use the same code everywhere and if i want to specify a leaderboard, I just pass it one! great stuff! thanks again